# python: extract parts from line when using different delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am reading `stdin` line by line:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    ...
```

Each line has following format:

```
: 1631373881:0;echo
```

I need to extract the first number (epoch time) and the command (last part after ';')

How can I extract these when the delimiter is not the same?

Comment: You can either use a regular expression or first split by one delimiter and then split the relevant part by the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input_str = ": 1631373881:0;echo".split(";")
command = input_str[-1]
number = input_str[0].split(":")[1].replace(" ","")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the lines always have the same format, you can bet on regular expressions:

```py
import re

MASK = re.compile(': (\\d+):\\d+;(.+)')

def extract(line):
  matches = MASK.findall(line)
  return matches[0] if matches else None

def test():
  assert extract(": 1631373881:0;echo test") == ("1631373881", "echo test")
```